# Recoding 11 binary variables into 1 using Stata

Tags: stata, ordinal

I am using Stata. So I have 11 separate variables, all "0 1" binary variables. I would like to recode them into one variable,  and at the same time I would like to group the values from variables 1-3 into one, 4-9 into one, and leave variables 10 and 11 as they are. So basically instead of having 11 variables, I want one recoded variable that I can tab, and it shows the following:

```
1 (composed of variable 1-3) frequency
2 (composed of variables 4-9) frequency
3 (composed of variable 10) frequency
4 (composed of variable 11) frequency
```

I started by using `rmax` to combine the first three variables, but don't know what to do after that! Can anyone help me?

This is what I started with, but not sure if I'm on the right track:

```
egen exclusion=rmax(avo_condition_1 avo_condition_2 avo_condition_3)

recode exclusion (0=0) (1=1)
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Note that a `recode` that just copies values is harmless but pointless.

Comment: @Nick thank you this is really useful. But what if for each observation there is more than one than one of the variables with the value 1, and I would like the frequencies to include each of those values, rather than restricting to one variable with a value 1 per observation?

Comment: Sounds more like a  row sum (use `egen`'s `rowsum()` function). But recoding and row summary are in principle different.

Comment: @Nick can you please tell me the syntax for using rowsum, if I want the variables grouped as I described earlier? Many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the new request. How does any grouping affect a sum? A row sum is just a row sum. You should edit your question to give a concrete example of what you want with realistic data.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that `v01` to `v11` are your old variables, and `x` will be your new combined variable. I'm going to assume that for each observation, *only one* of the variables `v01` to `v11` can take the value `1` and the rest must take the value `0`. Then do the following:

```
gen x = .
replace x = 10 if v01 | v02 | v03
replace x = 20 if v04 | v05 | v06 | v07 | v08 | v09
replace x = 30 if v10
replace x = 40 if v11
```

If you want, you can then label the values of `x`, but of course, this is optional.

```
label define xlab 10 "Var 01-03" 20 "Var 04-09" 30 "Var 10" 40 "Var 11"
label values x xlab
```

Comment: Another way to do this `gen x = cond(v11, 40, cond(v10, 30, cond(v04| v05|v06|v07|v08|v09, 20, cond(v01|v02|v03, 10, .))))`

Comment: Thank you this is really useful. But what if for each observation there is more than one than one of the variables with the value

Comment: @IvyJane That would depend on how you want conflicts to be resolved. If you want a `v11` to take precedence over `v10`, which takes precedence over `v04-v09`, which takes precedence over `v01`-`v03`, then the solutions given in this post still work.